# kotest integration login api status call

Tags: gherkin, kotest

I am trying to create a integration test using kotest with gherkin language for retrieving the Success or Failed status for login app action .
I have read that are multiple testing style from kotest [ Behaviour / Spec / Describe ] , but what is the best testing style to use ?
Do I have to configure as well a mock server ? how the given / when/ then should be written ?
Note : I am new to integration thing
Thanks a lot in advance